# Alinhar textarea com outros input com bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Galera eu estou fazendo um projetinho que é um site de pergunta e respostas tipo o yahoo so que estou tentando alinha a textarea com outros inputs  e nao to conseguindo ele esta assim [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

logo mais o codigo

```
<?php 
include"index.php";
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Title Page</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Perguntas</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form action="processar-pergunta.php" method="post" class="form-inline">


                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-2 col-xs-12">
                                                <label class=" control-label sr-only">Nome</label><input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o nome" size="12" required="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12">
                                                <label class=" control-label sr-only">Titulo</label><input type="text" name="titulo" size="48" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite titulo" required="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12">
                                                <br>
                                                <label class=" control-label sr-only">Pergunta</label> 
                                                <textarea name="pergunta" id="input" class="form-control" rows="12" cols="63" placeholder="Digite Pergunta" required="required" ></textarea>

                                                <div class="btn-group">
                                                    <br>
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger ">Enviar</button>
                                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" style="left: 10px" >Limpar</button>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara eu achei a forma como vc montou o Grid do form um pouco confusa, no seu caso acho que é melhor usar o [Horizontal Form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#forms-horizontal) do que o [Inline Form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#forms-inline) . Aqui tem o link da documentação completa https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#forms

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o Horizontal Form vc divide os campos em colunas, seguindo o Grid de forma bem simples.

**Veja como fica o código da imagem acima**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Title Page</title>
    
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
      <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
      <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        
     </head>
     <body>
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
         <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
           <h3 class="panel-title">Perguntas</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
           <form action="processar-pergunta.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class=" control-label sr-only">Nome</label>
                                <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o nome" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <label class=" control-label sr-only">Titulo</label>
                                <input type="text" name="titulo" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite titulo" required="">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label class=" control-label sr-only">Pergunta</label> 
                                <textarea name="pergunta" id="input" class="form-control" rows="12" placeholder="Digite Pergunta" required="required" ></textarea>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger ">Enviar</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" style="left: 10px" >Limpar</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>

           </form>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div> 
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
       
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Obrigado alinho certinho,cara eu queria ajuda pra aprende a usar o sistema de grid eu não sei muito bem usar você sabe algum artigo onde possa ajudar nisso?

Comment: @AdrianoRufino flexbox eh o que tem de melhor atualmente para construir layouts e tem o suporte melhor que o grid. Procure pelo guia de flexbox da Origamid que vai te ajudar muito e esta em português. Mas nesse caso estude bem o grid usado pelo Bootstrap, pois eh ele que vc esta usando no projeto pelo que vi. Se vc acha que a resposta resolveu o problema lembre-se de marcela como aceita nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas da resposta. ;)